# symfony2 ajax user search

Tags: ajax, symfony, search

I am working on a Symfony2 project where i have a user entity and i need an ajax search bar to search for my users. The problem is that in my ajax response the controller for some reason returns all users from the database.

1. js.

   ```
      $(".loading").hide();
      $("#form_recherche").submit(function(){
          $(".loading").show();
          var motcle = $("#acteurrecherche").val();
          var DATA = 'motcle=' + motcle;
          $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "{{ path('myapp_acteur_rechercher')}}",
              data: DATA,
              cache: false,
              success: function(data){
                  $('#resultats_recherche').html(data);
                  $(".loading").hide();
              }
          });
          return false;
      });
   ```
2. The controller

   ```
   public function rechercherAction()
   {

   $request = $this->get('request');

   if($request->isXmlHttpRequest())
   {
       $motcle = '';
       $motcle = $request->request->get('motcle');

       $em = $this->container->get('doctrine')->getEntityManager();

       if($motcle != '')
       {
           $qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();

           $qb->select('a')
               ->from('UtilisateursUtilisateursBundle:Utilisateurs', 'a')
               ->where("a.username LIKE :motcle")
               ->orderBy('a.username', 'ASC')
               ->setParameter('motcle', '%'.$motcle.'%');

           $query = $qb->getQuery();
           $acteurs = $query->getResult();
       }
       else {
           $acteurs = $em->getRepository('UtilisateursUtilisateursBundle:Utilisateurs')->findAll();
       }

       return $this->container->get('templating')->renderResponse('CodeRouteBackBundle:Utilisateur:Utilisateurs.html.twig', array(
           "per"=>$acteurs
       ));
   }
   else {
       return $this->utilisateurAction();
   }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check whether you are getting post parameter value in controller or not.

Try out below jquery code

```
$(".loading").hide();
$("#form_recherche").submit(function() {
    var motcle = $("#acteurrecherche").val();
    $(".loading").show();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            motcle: motcle
        },
        url: "{{ path('myapp_acteur_rechercher')}}",
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {
            $('#resultats_recherche').html(data);
            $(".loading").hide();
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: always it return this

Comment: return $this->container->get('templating')->renderResponse('CodeRouteBackBundle:Utilisateur:Utilisateurs.html.twig', array(
        "per"=>$acteurs

Comment: Uff my mistake... set " data" for twice... check updated answer

Comment: I don't understand you. please Can you explain more?